# How to access results of Sonar metrics for use with applications like PowerPivot

Tags: api, sonarqube, powerpivot

I'm trying to run a number of applications with known failure rates through Sonar, with hopes of deciding which metrics are most valuable in determining whether a particular application will fail. Ultimately I'll be making some sort of algorithm that will look at the outputs of whatever metrics I'm using and generate a score from 1 - 100. I've got about 21 applications put through Sonar, and the results have been stored in a MySQL database. I originally planned to use PowerPivot to find relationships in the data, but it seems like the formatting of the tables doesn't lend itself well to that. Other questions on stackoverflow have told me that Sonar's tables are unformatted, and I should instead use the Web Service API to get the information. I'm unfamiliar with API and was unsuccessful in trying to do what I wanted by looking at Sonar's documentation for API.

From an answer to another question:
http://nemo.sonarsource.org/api/timemachine?resource=org.apache.cxf:cxf&format=csv&metrics=ncloc,violations_density,comment_lines_density,public_documented_api_density,duplicated_lines_density,blocker_violations,critical_violations,major_violations,minor_violations

This looks very similar to what I'd like to have, except I'm only looking at each application once (I'm analyzing a sample of all the live applications on a grid), which means Timemachine isn't really what I'm looking for. Would it be possible to generate a similar table, except instead of the stats for a particular application per date, it showed the statistics for an application and all of its classes, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not familiar with the WS API, you can also create your own Sonar plugin to achieve whatever you want: it is written in Java and it will execute on every analysis you run. This way, in the code ot this custom plugin, you can do whatever you want: flush the metrics you need in an output file, push them into a third party system, ... etc.

Just take a look on [how to write a plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Getting+Started) (most probably you will create a Decorator). You have [concrete examples](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples) also to get started faster.

Comment: Links in your answer seems to be not working. Do you have updated link?